# How to return to a visited city?

Tags: 80-days

Some cities have a route each direction between them. For cities that have a route each way, is there a way to travel back to the other?

I can't figure out if this is an intentional gameplay limitation, or just something I am missing in the UI. The return route is clearly displayed when I explore the second city in the pair.